TSS Invalid Error When Switching to Thread in Linux 0.11 Kernel
I've been stuck on this segmentation fault issue for two weeks and would greatly appreciate any help. I'm working on an experiment based on Linux 0.11. One step involves adding a system call to create threads and initialize their TSS structure. However, I encounter a segmentation fault when switching to the thread using ljmp. Below is the relevant portion of my code:
int sys_pthread_create_kernel(pthread_t* thd, const pthread_attr_t* attr, void* start_routine) {
    struct thread_struct* q = (struct thread_struct*) get_free_page();
    struct thread_struct* main_thread = current->main_thread;
    int nt = find_empty_thread();
    if (!q || nt < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (nt >= NR_THREADS) {
        printk("Thread index out of bounds: %d\n", nt);
        free_page((unsigned long)q);
        return -1;
    }

    q->state = TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE;
    q->tid = last_tid;
    q->task = current;
    q->priority = main_thread->priority;
    q->counter = q->priority;
    q->tss.back_link = 0;
    q->tss.esp0 = PAGE_SIZE + (long) q;
    q->tss.esp = get_attr_from_user(attr)->stackaddr;
    q->tss.eflags = main_thread->tss.eflags;
    q->tss.eax = 0;
    q->tss.ss0 = 0x10;
    q->tss.cs = 0x0f;
    q->tss.eip = start_routine;
    q->tss.ecx = main_thread->tss.ecx;
    q->tss.edx = main_thread->tss.edx;
    q->tss.ebx = main_thread->tss.ebx;
    q->tss.ebp = main_thread->tss.ebp;
    q->tss.esi = main_thread->tss.esi;
    q->tss.edi = main_thread->tss.edi;
    q->tss.ss = main_thread->tss.ss & 0xffff;
    q->tss.es = main_thread->tss.es & 0xffff;
    q->tss.ds = main_thread->tss.ds & 0xffff;
    q->tss.fs = main_thread->tss.fs & 0xffff;
    q->tss.gs = main_thread->tss.gs & 0xffff;
    q->tss.ldt = _LDT(nt);
    q->tss.trace_bitmap = 0x80000000;
    q->tss.i387 = main_thread->tss.i387;
    set_tss_desc(gdt+(nt<<1)+FIRST_TSS_ENTRY, &(q->tss));
    set_ldt_desc(gdt+(nt<<1)+FIRST_LDT_ENTRY, &(current->ldt));
    put_fs_long(q->tid, thd);
    q->state = TASK_RUNNING;
    thread[nt] = q;
    return 0;
}

When I switch to the thread using ljmp, I get the following segmentation fault error:

I have checked common causes like jumping to a higher privilege segment or a non-existent TSS segment, but they don't seem to apply here.
